# Hapi Joi multiple alternative matches

Tags: hapi.js, joi

I would like field 'a' to be required when 'b' is either 'foo' or 'bar' but otherwise optional.

I see docs for a single field:

```
a: Joi.string().when('b', { is: 'foo', then: Joi.required() })
```

How would I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Joi.valid('bar', 'foo')` as the value of `is`:

```
a: Joi.string().when('b', { is: Joi.valid('bar', 'foo'), then: Joi.required() })
```